# VS2012 The resource "X" could not be resolved

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-phone, resourcedictionary

I have a Resources.xaml file in my project that contains a resource dictionary like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="GPHeaderFontSize" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Text" Value="BLAHHHHH"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have included this dictionary in App.xaml like so:

```
<Application x:Class="GoldenPlains.App" 
    xmlns="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"; 
    xmlns:x="schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"; 
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone" 
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">
    <Application.Resources> 
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GoldenPlains" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/> 
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="GPResources"> 
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> 
                <!-- Sometimes VS2012 complaining about path with blue line, please ignore it as path is correct --> 
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/GPResources.xaml"/> 
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style x:Key="GPRootOverlayBarStyle" TargetType="Image"> 
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/Images/root_brown_horizontal_bar.png"/> 
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="729"/> 
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/> 
                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/> 
            </style> 
    </Application.Resources>
    ...
    ...
</Application>
```

However when I try to reference an element in the resource dictionary from another Page.xaml file it cannot seem to resolve the resource.... 
eg:

I have tried using a binding like so:

```
<TextBlock Style="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.MyTextBlockStyle, Source=  {StaticResource GPResources}}"/>
```

it does not indicate that something is wrong but nothing shows up on the UI.

A point in the right direction would be great, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resource Dictionary definition in the App.xaml should be about like following example :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GoldenPlains" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/> 
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/GPResources.xaml"/> 
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- Other resources if you have -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then, when you need to apply style defined in Resources.xaml to a UI control, simply refer to the style's key/name :

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GPHeaderFontSize}" />
```

Notes: All resources need to be inside `ResourceDictionary` tag, including `LocalizedStrings`.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding the resource dictionary in the application resources node like the way you show here a couple of days ago but VS2012 forced me to specify a key for the top resource dictionary node, I noticed your example has it omitted. Everything else I am already doing. Cheers

Comment: mind posting your App.xaml? I tried this codes in VS2012 too, Windows Phone 8 project. it worked as it should

Comment: <Application.Resources><ResourceDictionary x:Key="GPResources">
      <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
          <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary></Application.Resources>

Comment: Is that all? I know that part as you posted it in question. I meant if you have more in App.xaml, please include it in question. If you don't have other than those you posted already, then please try to change them like I showed in answer. I'm sure it should work

Comment: The only other things in there are the standard Localized strings namespace declaration and some custom styles I defined, I don't have code with me at the moment, I will give yours a try and get back to you. Cheers

Comment: I was able to pull the file data remotely, please see below:

Comment: <Application
    x:Class="GoldenPlains.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone">

Comment: Application.Resources>
        <local:LocalizedStrings xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GoldenPlains" x:Key="LocalizedStrings"/>

        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="GPResources">
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <!-- Sometimes VS2012 complaining about path with blue line, please ignore it as path is correct -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/GPResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

Comment: <Style x:Key="GPRootOverlayBarStyle" TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/Images/root_brown_horizontal_bar.png"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="729"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
            </style>
    </Application.Resources>

Comment: @SeanRyan See my updated answer for solution. And also, avoid posting codes in comment. Edit your answer to include those codes next time.

Comment: Hi yes that was a copy paste error, the original code is same as edited one. Cheers anyway

Comment: note that you put `<local:LocalizedStrings` outside `ResourceDictionary` when it should be inside. Put it inside `ResourceDictionary`, and it will work.

Comment: Hi har07, cheers now it is working, I am not sure why putting the LocalizedStrings resource path definition into the top node of ResourceDictionary made the difference though. Thanks

Comment: not necessarily on top. When using resource dictionary, any other resources should be defined inside resource dictionary, can be at the top, bottom, order doesn't matter. Putting `<local:LocalizedStrings>` inside `<Application.Resources>` but outside `<ResourceDictionary>` was the wrong step you did.